# Handling Service call errors with ErraiCallback

Tags: java, gwt, errai

What is the requirement in a Service implementation so that the `ErrorCallback` will be able to print the error message on the UI like.

I tried injecting a `ErrorCallback` in the Service call code, and when I print the `Message` object its null.

What should be the Service implementation look like, should I put `throws SomeException` on the implementation method? Or?

```
myService.call(new RemoteCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void callback(String response) {
        Multimap<String, String> state =  ArrayListMultimap.create();
        state.put("hash", response);
        submit.go(state);
    }
}, new ErrorCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean error(Message message, Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        Window.alert("Error: " + message);
        return false;
    }
}).createmy(my);
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the code that isn't working for you?

Comment: What should be the implementation of myService method createmy() look like? Should it contain a 'throws Exception' for the ErrorCallback to return non null message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as stated in the question. The exception thrown by the remote service should be delivered to you in the `throwable` parameter to your `ErrorCallback.error()` method.

You only need to put a throws clause on the remote interface if you want to throw a checked exception. Unchecked exceptions should work as you've done it. In fact, there is a disadvantage to declaring checked exceptions on remote interfaces: you will have to surround your RPC calls with a useless try/catch block, like this:

```
@Remote public interface MyService {
  Result dangerousOperation() throws MyCheckedException;
}
```

and the calling code:

```
try {
  myService.call(new RemoteCallback<Result>() {
    @Override
    public void callback(final Result result) {
      Window.alert("Yay, got a result: " + result);
    }
  },
  new BusErrorCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean error(Message message, Throwable throwable) {
      Window.alert("Got an exception from the remote service: " + throwable);
      return false;
    }
  }).dangerousOperation();
}
catch (MyCheckedException e) {
  throw new AssertionError(); // can't happen: caller stub won't throw this
}
```

So you're probably better off with the unchecked exception.

Comment: BTW: BusErrorCallback is the new type to use for RPC calls in Errai 3.x. In Errai 2.x, ErrorCallback is correct.

Comment: I'm actually using errai-jaxrs

Comment: That's the kind of thing that you need to mention when you are asking a question. The answer can only be as relevant and accurate as the question you've asked.

Comment: Yah... sorry about this, I was dozing off last night when I asked this question.